# JSLint -Expected '{' instead saw 'type'

Tags: javascript, jslint

JSLint keeps returning the following error: *Expected '{' instead saw 'type'*, how can I fix it?

```
var pfx = ['webkit', 'moz', 'MS', 'o', '']; 
function prefixedEventListener(element, type, callback) {
    for (var p = 0; p < pfx.length; p++) {
      if (!pfx[p]) type = type.toLowerCase();
      element.addEventListener(pfx[p]+type, callback, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think  as per JSlint rules, `if` should have braces

```
if (!pfx[p]) {
  type = type.toLowerCase();
}
```

From JSLint docs,

**Blocks** (http://www.jslint.com/help.html)

JSLint expects blocks with `function`, `if`, `switch`, `while`, `for`, `do`, and `try` statements and nowhere else.

JSLint expects that `if`, `while`, `do` and `for` statements will be made with blocks `{` that is, with statements enclosed in braces`}`.

JavaScript allows an if to be written like this:

```
if (condition)
    statement;
```

That form is known to contribute to mistakes in projects where many programmers are working on the same code. That is why JSLint expects the use of a block:

```
if (condition) {
    statements;
}
```

Experience shows that this form is more resilient.

Answer (score 2):

From [Lint docs](http://www.jslint.com/help.html)

> JSLint expects that if, while, do and for statements will be made with blocks {that is, with statements enclosed in braces}.

So the problem with the line

```
if (!pfx[p]) type = type.toLowerCase();
```

Though valid, the line is more confuses and error prone for lint and it won't consider that as a valid **block**

Just to make JSLint smile you may rewrite it to

```
if (!pfx[p]) {    
type = type.toLowerCase();    
}
```